# why get_header doesn't work twice in a test

Tags: templates, wp-blog-header.php

I'm trying to test a template. It's working fine individually until I run all the tests altogether and the tests fail.

```
protected function load_template() {
    do_action( 'template_redirect' );
    $template = false;
    if   ( is_404()         && $template = get_404_template()           ) :
    elseif ( is_search()         && $template = get_search_template()        ) :
    elseif ( is_front_page()     && $template = get_front_page_template()    ) :
    elseif ( is_home()         && $template = get_home_template()          ) :
    elseif ( is_post_type_archive() && $template = get_post_type_archive_template() ) :
    elseif ( is_tax()           && $template = get_taxonomy_template()     ) :
    elseif ( is_attachment()     && $template = get_attachment_template()    ) :
        remove_filter('the_content', 'prepend_attachment');
    elseif ( is_single()         && $template = get_single_template()        ) :
    elseif ( is_page()         && $template = get_page_template()          ) :
    elseif ( is_category()     && $template = get_category_template()      ) :
    elseif ( is_tag()           && $template = get_tag_template()           ) :
    elseif ( is_author()         && $template = get_author_template()        ) :
    elseif ( is_date()         && $template = get_date_template()          ) :
    elseif ( is_archive()       && $template = get_archive_template()       ) :
    elseif ( is_comments_popup() && $template = get_comments_popup_template() ) :
    elseif ( is_paged()       && $template = get_paged_template()         ) :
    else :
        $template = get_index_template();
    endif;
    /**
     * Filter the path of the current template before including it.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param string $template The path of the template to include.
     */

    if ( $template = apply_filters( 'template_include', $template ) )
        include( $template );
    return;
}
```

My test is testing meta which will be shown from `get_header` but when the first test passed the second test doesn't have `<meta>` tags, I found out that `<?php get_header(); ?>` returns nothing if the tests run altogether. Am I missing something and why if the tests run altogether the first one passed but not the second and so on?

UPDATE:

Here's my test method

```
public function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();

    $this->setup_permalink_structure();
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'GET';
    $this->setOutputCallback( function() {
        return '';
    });
}

protected function get_view_output_as_dom( $path ) {
    ob_start();
    $this->go_to( $path );
    $this->load_template();
    $output = ob_get_clean();
    var_dump('start here');
    var_dump($output);
    ob_flush();

    $html5 = new HTML5();
    $dom = $html5->loadHTML($output);

    return $dom;
}
```

`get_view_output_as_dom` will return DOM for test. And this is my test

```
$metas = qp( $dom, 'meta' );
$this->assertMetaTags($expected_home_tags, $metas);

private function assertMetaTags( $expected_tags, $metas ) {
        $inspector = array();
        foreach( $expected_tags as $key => $value ) {
            foreach( $metas as $meta ) {
                if( $meta->attr( 'property' ) == $key ) {
                    array_push( $inspector, $key );
                    $this->assertEquals( $value, $meta->attr( 'content' ) );
                }
            }
        }

        if( count( $inspector ) != count( $expected_tags ) ) {
            var_dump( $inspector );
            $this->fail( 'one or more attributes are missing' );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tests should always be ran in isolation, you shouldn't be running them on an instance that's not clean due to past tests. In this case you need to run each test in its own instance of WordPress. When the test finishes, make a new request to do your second test. Beyond that there simply isn't enough information to answer this. We can't see the rest of your class, what testing framework you're using, what you're testing, etc etc

Comment: Thanks for your replay and apologize for not including more info. I've added more already.